# Rapid way to represent Map<K, V> as Map <U, List<V>>

Tags: java, collections, dictionary, concurrency

***I have:*** `Map<Long, Peer>`, where key is `peerUid` and  `value` is `Peer`. Each `Peer` is something like user session container and contains `UserAuthorities`:

```
public class Peer {
  private UserAuthorities authorities;
  //...
}
```

***I need:***

Quickly do:

1. [in half of requests] Get all peers: `List<Peer>`
2. [in each request] Get all peers grouped by `UserAuthorities`: `Map<UserAuthorities, List<Peer>>`.
3. [once for browser tab] Add new peer (with null UserAuthorities and after some time set user authorities)
4. [arrely] Remove peer by `peerUid` or all peers by `UserAuthorities`
5. Finally achieve all four statements above in concurrent environment

***Problem:***

At the moment when I add new `Peer` to the map, I HAVEN'T `UserAuthorities`. It means that `UserAuthorities` are muttable.

***Questions:***

1. Is there any way to get `Map<UserAuthorities, List<Peer>>` from `Map<Long, Peer>` quickly? (Aproximate number of peers is about 20; but that action will be proceeded on each user request)
2. If no, how can I achieve that if Peer.userAuthorities is mutable field?

***P.S:*** When `UserAuthorities` are changed?

The answer is very simple - only once on log in. User goes to home page, he get `Peer` on the server side, but haven't got any authorities yet. So he loges in and get them.

Comment: Did you mean *group by* `UserAuthorities`?

Comment: @RohitJain is that API method?

Comment: No. Just asking. You said *sort*, but that looks more like grouping.

Comment: @RohitJain yes, I ment `groupBy`. Thanks

Comment: @RohitJain maybe `TreeMap`? But again - `UserAuthorities` are muttable

Comment: I think that the mutability of 'authorities' is a crucial point here (this was not a political statement). No collection whatsoever can be informed about a change in this field as long as there is no built-in notification mechanism. So the only choice would be to "transparently" create the queried data (where this field is relevant) from scratch each time, what probably is what you want to avoid. Can you elaborate how/when the `authorities` field is modified? Or IS there even some possible notification mechanism (e.g. a `interface PeerListener { void authorityChanged() }` that can be added?

Comment: @Marco13 see P.S. section of my question

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, so technically, it might have to be deleted - But something like this can hardly be discussed in a comment...:

So I assume that the data structure should look like this interface `LoginDatastructure`, is this correct?

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

class UserAuthorities {}
class Peer 
{
    private UserAuthorities authorities;
}

interface LoginDatastructure
{
    // 1. Get all peers
    List<Peer> getAllPeers();

    // 2. Get all peers grouped by UserAuthorities
    Map<UserAuthorities, List<Peer>> getPeersByUserAuthority();

    // 3. Add new peer (with null UserAuthorities 
    // and after some time set user authorities)
    void addPeer(Peer peer);

    // 4a Remove peer by peerUid 
    void removePeer(long peerUid);

    // 4b. Remove peer by peerUid or all peers by UserAuthorities
    void removePeers(UserAuthorities u);
}
```

Where does your `Map<Long, Peer>` occur in this example?

Concerning 3.: When the peer is added, and it has a `null` UserAuthority, should it be included in the list that is returned by method 1? And should it be included in the map that is returned by method 2?

```
List<Peer> peersWithNull = map.get(null);
```

?

Concerning the changing UserAuthority: Is it possible to *inform* this data structure when the User Authority changes? That is, can the `LoginDatastructure` have an additional method like

```
void userAuthorityWasSet(Peer peer);
```

that will be called when the UserAuthority of the given peer changed?

Concerning point 5, the concurrency: Is there any reason not to blatantly make all of these methods `synchronized`?

---

EDIT: Concerning the synchronization: What kind of thread-safety do you expect? For example, when one Peer is added, should this automatically become visible in all Lists that someone may have obtained from the Map of method 2? Should these lists also be updated when the authority is set? In any case, until now, the methods are primarily adding/removing elements to/from the data structure, so I think making them `synchonrized` would not have any considerable performance impact (unless, of course, the data structures, like the map, are rebuilt from scratch during each call - but I think you wanted to avoid this anyhow.

In any case, I have the feeling that StackOverflow might not be the right place for this kind of *discussion*....

Comment: answer for concerning#3 yes: peers with `null` authorities should be included. Also method which changes UserAuthorities is in my class, I can modify it. And the last - it seems bad idea for me do make all methods `synchronized`, because my app based on non-blocking io (websockets) and there will be many users who simultaneously will do operations with the same peers collection.

Comment: @Volodymyr Bakhmatiuk Addded an EDIT, but think that it will be hard to quickly come to a solution here...

Answer (score -1):

1. Check the `Map` API: `Map#values()`
2. ?
3. Check the `Map` API: `Map#remove()`
4. ?
5. ?

Comment: I'm familiar with map API. `map@values()` returns List. Than to sort that list by UserDetails parameter I should iterate through all list O(n) and perform O(n) `equals` calls. It's very slow

Comment: Yes, you could keep another view on the map values sorted by some parameter and backed by the concrete values if this improves your speed significantly.